# ASP.NET MVC EditorFor DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, editorfor

How to implement EditorFor DateTime?

I already have editors for Date and Time separately. Can I use it for my DateTime editor?

Are there any suggestions, how to do it?

**Date editor:**

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, (Model != default(DateTime) ? Model.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "date form-control" })
```

**Time editor:**

```
@model DateTime?

@Html.TextBox(string.Empty, (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("HH:mm") : string.Empty), new { @class = "time form-control" })
```

I am using jQuery UI datepicker for date editor. Timepicker is also jQuery plugin.

Comment: Can't you just combine them? For example `@Html.EditorFor(Model.TheDate) - @Html.EditorFor(Model.TheTime)`. Do you need different formats?

Comment: @AndreiV this will generate two inputs... not great for model binding, I would say.

Comment: Could you show the code of your Date and Time editors ? Maybe you can do some refactoring, or use a custom HtmlHelper instead of Templates...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, add a hidden then?

Comment: @AndreiV Yes, everything's possible, but then you'll need some javascript to populate that hidden field. It's not really pure "reuse" of existing...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, agree. It depends on what you are willing to sacrifice.

Answer (score 4):

Create DateTime.cshtml in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates that contains:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<System.DateTime?>
@Html.TextBox("", string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", 
              Model.HasValue ? Model : null), new { @class = "dateTimePicker" })
```

And use some jquery datepicker. think this one works with default jquery ui one.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use it for my DateTime editor?

With this [JQuery TimePicker plugin](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) you can definitely have one Editor field.