# Can I change the width of an EditorFor with data annotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, editorformodel

There's a few questions on similar topics. However, they don't actually address my issue.

[DisplayFormat for TextBoxFor in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14700873/displayformat-for-textboxfor-in-mvc)

[Display a formatted date in an EditorFor()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943797/display-a-formatted-date-in-an-editorfor)

[ASP.NET MVC EditorFor DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21548638/asp-net-mvc-editorfor-datetime)

I've been searching and reading up and cannot find an answer to this.

I'm currently using this to format my input box:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { style = "width: 30px;" })
```

From my model, I have the brief data annotation:

```
[Required, Range(1, 100)]
public int Quantity { get; set; }
```

So I get this:

[image]

When I use

```
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.Quantity, new { style = "width: 30px;" })
```

I get this:

[image]

What I want is the scroll, but to format the width.

I'm wondering, is there a way to format the width of an `EditorFor` with `data annotations`? If not, what is the easiest way to make such a format, to avoid repetition.. `bootstrap`, `css`? I'm not happy with the inline styling.

Comment: Are you using MVC-5.1+. If not you cannot pass html attributes to the default editor template (you will need to create your own custom `EditorTemplate`). Alternatively use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, new { type = "number ", style = "width: 30px;" })`

Comment: Sure, I'll give you a few options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, your using MVC-4. You cannot pass html attributes to the `EditorFor()` method unless your using MVC-5.1 or higher (refer the [release notes](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/mvc51-release-notes) - the section on *Bootstrap support for editor templates*)

One option is to use the `TextBoxFor()` method and pass `type="number"` to render the browsers numeric control

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Quantity, new { type = "number ", style = "width: 30px;" })
```

Another would be to create a custom `EditorTemplate` (say `_NumericControl.cshtml`)

```
@model System.Int32
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { type = "number ", style = "width: 30px;" })
```

and call it using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Quantity, "_NumericControl")`

but this would really only be of any real benefit if the template were also to include other html elements, for example `@Html.LabelFor(m => m)` and `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)` and perhaps even the associated button so that the `EditorFor()` method renders all elements.